# Lucee ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I'm converting a site from ColdFusion to Lucee (for the first time).  In ColdFusion, after using the cfajaximport tag, I can run JS code similar to this:
`ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm('runMe', 'runCode.cfm', callback_testMe, errorHandler_testMe);`

I seem to be unable to run this in Lucee.  I'm looking for some kind of Lucee alternative, but can't seem to find anything.

Basically, I'm wanting to submit form data, run some server side stuff, then return the results without refreshing the page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since you want to make your site future-proof by switchting to Lucee, you might as well get rid of the horrible legacy ACF JavaScript stuff. You might want to start here: [ColdFusion UI - The Right Way](https://static.raymondcamden.com/cfuitherightway/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucee does not have CF UI tags, you're going to have to do this with jQuery AJAX or similar.

```
var formID = "runMe"; // formId Param
$("#"+formID).on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent page load
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", // httpMethod Param
        url: "runCode.cfm", // URL Param
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data); // callbackhandler
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(thrownError); // errorHandler
        }
    });
})
```

This should do exactly the same thing and I even pointed out the similar params from `ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm`